# Serialized data in my sql field as text

Tags: php, mysql, jsonserializer

I have orders details as serialized in the TEXT Type of mysql field. Recently one of customer add a big order which a TEXT type field was unable to process. So Now I want to change the TEXT to LONGTEXT. Would change of FIELD TYPE have any effect to existing entered data(baskets)??

I have a a long serialized string of Basket with last items missing. Can I still make it recover to at least with those items which are entered. I know its kind of difficult to play with serialized data. but still curious if there will be any way to make that basket (orders) recover?

serialized data is something like this. it is sample for one item in basket.

```
O:6:"basket":1:{s:8:"order_id";b:0;s:8:"contents";a:1:{i:2375;a:2:{s:7:"details";a:21:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"2375";s:11:"category_id";s:2:"68";s:10:"stock_code";s:5:"80200";s:4:"name";s:8:"Angelica";s:11:"description";s:1474:" ";s:8:"complete";s:1:"0";s:7:"display";s:1:"1";s:10:"meta_title";s:69:".";s:14:"botanical_name";s:21:"Angelica archangelica";s:6:"height";s:10:"2.5m (8ft)";s:6:"spread";s:10:"1.5m (5ft)";s:5:"scent";s:7:"neither";s:8:"position";s:7:"not_set";s:12:"availability";s:3:"NOW";s:8:"climbing";s:2:"on";s:7:"borders";s:2:"on";s:10:"containers";s:2:"on";s:7:"rhs_agm";s:0:"";s:10:"greenhouse";s:2:"on";s:7:"vegplot";s:2:"on";}s:7:"options";a:1:{i:3358;a:4:{s:8:"quantity";d:1;s:4:"unit";s:8:"Per pack";s:5:"value";s:4:"1.45";s:8:"adjusted";b:0;}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to recover that data you can change `text` to `longtext` this will not impact existing data but can not recover your recent missing row.

Comment: there were 50 products which ordered. while only 48 has been listed and text is truncated. is there any possibility that I can make these 48 work. so at least customer won't need to order for all 50 products. he just can add missing 2 records.

Comment: You can query with the condition and fetch only those 48 products only you can also handle this in PHP level

Comment: in fact half truncated string of serialize object is corrupted. I tried to remove last half written item. and close the brackets as well. but when i unserialize it. it return false.